# Will I keep the credits that I redeemed from a Google Play voucher if I get a new phone?

Tags: google-play-store

I bought a new phone, and I have redeemed a £25 Google Play voucher on my Play Store account.

I need to take back my phone. If I get a new phone, will I still have the £25 on my Google Play account?

Comment: Probably, but I'm sure this depends on the contract with whomever sold you the phone, and their return policy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the credits / load is tied to your account. So, it will still be there, as long as you use the same Google account.